# Como crear una busqueda con laravel

Tags: laravel

Hola tengo un enlace que funciona asi:

```
<a href ="{{url("/administrador/$product->id")}}">Ver</a>
```

aqui la id se carga de la base

y tengo una vista que recibe el id  y lo muestra

¿Podría lograr la misma URL usando un formulario enviando la id manualmente llenando un campo de texto ?

Comment: Imagino que estarás usando un controlador para obtener el "$product". Estaría bien saber como lo has hecho...
Respondiendo a tu pregunta, create esa url en el controlador y la metes en un campo tipo hidden (sino quieres que se vea) o al campo del action del formulario igual que como sacarías cualquier campo,
acuérdate de agregar el código blade al formulario {{ csrf_field() }}.
Recuerda que sino vas a enviar datos es mejor usar <a> y si vas a enviar datos entonces usa el <form>

Comment: ¿La idea es llenar un campo de texto con el id de la URL? no entiendo bien.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

puedes hacerlo realizando una redirección.

```
public function redireccion(Request $request)
{
    $productid = $request->input('productid');

    return redirect("/administrador/$productid");   
}
```